# Combine two data generator to train a CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dataset, generator, data-augmentation

I am trying to train a model using a dataset that i split in two parts, for each part i create a different ImageDataGenerator using keras and tensorflow.

my question is , how to combine the data from both of my generators to train the model. I don t want t use each one separately

tnx for all

Answer (score 3):

You have divided all your data into two different directories; now you want to train the model with data from those two directories.

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. The Keras ImageDataGenerator [`flow_from_directory`](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method) method has a `follow_links` parameter. You can use `follow_links`. Create a separate directory according to your needs and desired class structure. Inside it, create symlinks from your original data directory. In the image below, you can use the `data` directory as your main input directory.

   ```
   .
   ├── Directory1/
   │   ├── Class1/
   │   └── Class2/
   ├── Directory2/
   │   ├── Class1/
   │   └── Class2/
   └── Data/
       ├── Class1/
       │   ├── symlink_to_Directory1_Class1
       │   └── symlink_to_Directory2_Class1
       └── Class2/
           ├── symlink_to_Directory1_Class2
           └── symlink_to_Directory2_Class2
   ```
2. Made two different [`ImageDatagenerator`](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class)  for two different directories. And then merge them as one. In that case, the batch sizes of the sub-generators have to be determined in proportion to the number of data in the respective directories.

   *Batch size of sub-generators*: [image: b = \frac{B \times n}{\sum{n}}]

   ```
   Where,
   b = Batch Size Of Any Sub-generator
   B = Desired Batch Size Of The Merged Generator
   n = Number Of Images In That Directory Of Sub-generator
   the sum of n = Total Number Of Images In All Directories
   ```

   See the code below

   ```py
   from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
   from keras.utils import Sequence
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np
   import os


   class MergedGenerators(Sequence):

       def __init__(self, batch_size, generators=[], sub_batch_size=[]):
           self.generators = generators
           self.sub_batch_size = sub_batch_size
           self.batch_size = batch_size

       def __len__(self):
           return int(
               sum([(len(self.generators[idx]) * self.sub_batch_size[idx])
                    for idx in range(len(self.sub_batch_size))]) /
               self.batch_size)

       def __getitem__(self, index):
           """Getting items from the generators and packing them"""

           X_batch = []
           Y_batch = []
           for generator in self.generators:
               if generator.class_mode is None:
                   x1 = generator[index % len(generator)]
                   X_batch = [*X_batch, *x1]

               else:
                   x1, y1 = generator[index % len(generator)]
                   X_batch = [*X_batch, *x1]
                   Y_batch = [*Y_batch, *y1]

           if self.generators[0].class_mode is None:
               return np.array(X_batch)
           return np.array(X_batch), np.array(Y_batch)


   def build_datagenerator(dir1=None, dir2=None, batch_size=32):
       n_images_in_dir1 = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(dir1)])
       n_images_in_dir2 = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(dir2)])

       # Have to set different batch size for two generators as number of images
       # in those two directories are not same. As we have to equalize the image
       # share in the generators
       generator1_batch_size = int((n_images_in_dir1 * batch_size) /
                                   (n_images_in_dir1 + n_images_in_dir2))

       generator2_batch_size = batch_size - generator1_batch_size

       generator1 = ImageDataGenerator(
           rescale=1. / 255,
           shear_range=0.2,
           zoom_range=0.2,
           rotation_range=5.,
           horizontal_flip=True,
       )

       generator2 = ImageDataGenerator(
           rescale=1. / 255,
           zoom_range=0.2,
           horizontal_flip=False,
       )

       # generator2 has different image augmentation attributes than generaor1
       generator1 = generator1.flow_from_directory(
           dir1,
           target_size=(128, 128),
           color_mode='rgb',
           class_mode=None,
           batch_size=generator1_batch_size,
           shuffle=True,
           seed=42,
           interpolation="bicubic",
       )

       generator2 = generator2.flow_from_directory(
           dir2,
           target_size=(128, 128),
           color_mode='rgb',
           class_mode=None,
           batch_size=generator2_batch_size,
           shuffle=True,
           seed=42,
           interpolation="bicubic",
       )

       return MergedGenerators(
           batch_size,
           generators=[generator1, generator2],
           sub_batch_size=[generator1_batch_size, generator2_batch_size])


   def test_datagen(batch_size=32):
       datagen = build_datagenerator(dir1="./asdf",
                                     dir2="./asdf2",
                                     batch_size=batch_size)

       print("Datagenerator length (Batch count):", len(datagen))

       for batch_count, image_batch in enumerate(datagen):
           if batch_count == 1:
               break

           print("Images: ", image_batch.shape)

           plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
           for i in range(image_batch.shape[0]):
               plt.subplot(1, batch_size, i + 1)
               plt.imshow(image_batch[i], interpolation='nearest')
               plt.axis('off')
               plt.tight_layout()


   test_datagen(4)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand what you want to achieve exactly without un minimal code sample describing it. I mean, how to combine the generator? Alternate between them two?

Anyway, you can create your own data generator using keras [Sequence objects](https://keras.io/utils/).

You can find example of a custom data generator [here](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly).